# Rcpp: How to ensure deep copy of a NumericMatrix?

Tags: r, rcpp

Suppose, I have a Rcpp::NumericMatrix A. I want to make an identical copy (not pointer copy) of A into another Rcpp::NumericMatrix B. Is this the correct way of doing this job?

```
Rcpp::NumericMatrix B(Rcpp::clone(A));
```

Also what is the difference between the above line and the following:

```
Rcpp::NumericMatrix B(A);
```

Comment: Essentially, yes -- use `Rcpp::clone()` to ensure a deep copy. When you construct an Rcpp object from a `SEXP` (or `Rcpp` object) of the same type, you instead get two objects using the same underlying memory for the data.