# Rcpp and move semantic

Tags: c++, c++11, rcpp, move-semantics

I implemented an algorithm in `C++` that returns as output a huge array of elements. Now, I would like to implement a wrapper in `Rcpp` so that I will be able to call this function by using `R`.

I specified in the Makevars file the following setting:

> PKG_CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11

So that I can use the C++11 version.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix compute(int width, int height)
{
  vector<data_t> weights(width * height);
  compute_weights(weights);

  NumericMatrix mat(height, width);
  copy(begin(weights), end(weights), mat.begin());

  return mat;
}
```

The above wrapper function remains efficient if the NumericMatrix is moved when returned by the function, otherwise a new object will be created.

Does `Rcpp` exploit the move semantics? And if not, are there any workarounds to avoid the construction of the copy?

Comment: I don't know anything about rcpp, but if you need a workaround I'm sure it will be to not return by value.

Comment: This should NRVO on any decent compiler, move semantics or not.

Comment: Notwithstanding NRVO, move semantics are not part of Rcpp. They are part of your class. Does your NumericMatrix have an rvalue reference constructor? If it does, any standard conforming compiler will call it.

Comment: @SergeyA NumericMatrix is an Rcpp class, not mine. This is what I am asking.

Comment: @Nick, you should have it's header file available, right? Look into it and see.

Comment: Citing Romain's comment [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/122), *"Rcpp does not implement move semantics for Rcpp classes. And a move constructor or assignment operator generated automatically by the compiler probably does not do the right thing."*. Also, note that you can specify the attribute `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]`, as a less intrusive alternative to editing `Makevars`.

Answer (score 0):

> The above wrapper function remains efficient if the NumericMatrix is moved when returned by the function, otherwise a new object will be created.
>
> ... And if not, are there any workarounds to avoid the construction of the copy?

I think that only a shallow copy is created by the copy constructor so there should not be any copy. See [Rcpp: How to ensure deep copy of a NumericMatrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015321/rcpp-how-to-ensure-deep-copy-of-a-numericmatrix) and

- https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/b3b0bea7403d9836397148fa310b86eb24923aba/inst/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h#L74
- which calls https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/b3b0bea7403d9836397148fa310b86eb24923aba/inst/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h#L62-L67

This is also confirmed by this example

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector allocate_the_vec(R_xlen_t n_ele){
  Rcpp::NumericVector out(n_ele);
  return out;
}

/*** R
# got 16 GB ram on my laptop. 3 x 7 is an issue but 2 x 7 is not
how_large <- as.integer(7 * 10^9 / 8)
the_large_vec_1 <- allocate_the_vec(how_large)
object.size(the_large_vec_1)
the_large_vec_2 <- allocate_the_vec(how_large)
*/
```