# Rcpp requires a copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, rcpp

I'm trying to export some C++11 functionality to R, using Rcpp. Some of these functions return their result using a `std::unique_ptr`. This stuff cannot be copied. The MCVE below uses `std::unique_ptr<std::string>` to illustrate the errors.

I have created a class around the `unique_ptr`, in the hopes of making all of this possible, but to no avail. This is the `PtrClassOwner` below. The function `createClassWrapper` calls the original `createClass`, to stick the `unique_ptr` in a `PtrClassOwner` object.

```
#include <RcppCommon.h>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

// Stuff to wrap:

using PtrClass = std::unique_ptr<std::string>;

PtrClass createClass() { return PtrClass{new std::string("boo")}; }

// ---

class PtrClassOwner {
public:
    PtrClass string;
};

PtrClassOwner createClassWrapper() { return PtrClassOwner{createClass()}; }

RCPP_EXPOSED_WRAP(PtrClassOwner); // Rcpp-extending vignette says RCPP_EXPORT_WRAP, which doesn't exist.
RCPP_EXPOSED_AS(PtrClassOwner);

#include <Rcpp.h>

RCPP_MODULE(Class){
    using namespace Rcpp;

    class_<PtrClassOwner>("PtrClass");

    function("createClass", &createClassWrapper);
}
```

This the first error reported by GCC (v 5.4, on Linux):

```
In file included from /home/cris/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:195:0,
                 from rcpp_module.cpp:1:
/home/cris/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap.h: In instantiation of ‘SEXPREC* Rcpp::internal::wrap_dispatch(const T&, Rcpp::traits::wrap_type_module_object_tag) [with T = PtrClassOwner; SEXP = SEXPREC*]’:
/home/cris/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap_end.h:30:38:   required from ‘SEXPREC* Rcpp::wrap(const T&) [with T = PtrClassOwner; SEXP = SEXPREC*]’
/home/cris/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap_end.h:35:20:   required from ‘SEXPREC* Rcpp::module_wrap_dispatch(const T&, Rcpp::traits::normal_wrap_tag) [with T = PtrClassOwner; SEXP = SEXPREC*]’
/home/cris/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap.h:922:40:   required from ‘SEXPREC* Rcpp::module_wrap(const T&) [with T = PtrClassOwner; SEXP = SEXPREC*]’
/home/cris/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/module/Module_generated_CppFunction.h:34:50:   required from ‘SEXPREC* Rcpp::CppFunction0<RESULT_TYPE>::operator()(SEXPREC**) [with RESULT_TYPE = PtrClassOwner; SEXP = SEXPREC*]’
rcpp_module.cpp:26:1:   required from here
/home/cris/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap.h:759:54: error: use of deleted function ‘PtrClassOwner::PtrClassOwner(const PtrClassOwner&)’
             return Rcpp::internal::make_new_object<T>(new T(object));
                                                      ^
rcpp_module.cpp:9:7: note: ‘PtrClassOwner::PtrClassOwner(const PtrClassOwner&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class PtrClassOwner {
       ^
```

The problem seems to be that, to wrap the object into an R object, it needs to be copied. [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507105/rcpp-and-move-semantic) is from someone running into a similar issue, but there are no answers.

I have created a similar interface to Python, where the Python object just contains a pointer to the C++ object. I find it strange that Rcpp tries to copy the object to wrap it.

Is there a way around this issue? Is it possible to wrap only a pointer to the object in an R type, and somehow still properly manage its lifetime? I'm open to any solutions, I'm not set on using Rcpp, it just seemed the most straightforward method to export this functionality.

Comment: That's pretty long, but you don't really say what you _really_ want to do.  Maybe discuss it over on the rcpp-devel list instead?   And Rcpp Modules is _one_ way of interface C++ from R ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: I think I described this: I need to wrap a type that can't be copied. I have a pointer to it, which is managed by a `unique_ptr`. I have some functions that use this object. I want to call these functions from within R. I can take this to the rcpp-devel list, if that is a better place to ask.

Comment: There are some things that are _very_ idiosyncratic to the _R_ interface to C which is the one we have to eventually fiddle things into as well.  So _everything_ has to become a `SEXP` type.  You may want to look into `Rcpp::XPtr`.  It is not the most documented area but there are some posts here too.  I have the feeling you can't quite do what you want to do the way you are planning to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution I've found so far is to extract the pointer from the `std::unique_ptr` and create a `std::shared_ptr` from it.  Rcpp will wrap this, as it can be copied.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

// Stuff to wrap:

using PtrClass = std::unique_ptr<std::string>;

PtrClass createClass() { return PtrClass{new std::string("boo")}; }

// ---

using ShPtrClass = std::shared_ptr<PtrClass::element_type>;

class PtrClassOwner {
public:
    ShPtrClass shPtrClass;
    PtrClassOwner(PtrClass ptr) : shPtrClass(ptr.release()) {}
};

PtrClassOwner createClassWrapper() { return PtrClassOwner{createClass()}; }

std::string getString(PtrClassOwner const& ptr) {
    return *(ptr.shPtrClass);
}

RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(PtrClassOwner);

RCPP_MODULE(Class){
    using namespace Rcpp;
    class_<PtrClassOwner>("PtrClass");
    function("createClass", &createClassWrapper, "createClass method");
    function("getString", &getString, "getString method");
}
```

Comment: That's nice. You probably want to make C++11 use explicit with the plugin, and maybe stick to `Rcpp.h` as recommended.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: You're right, it also works with `Rcpp.h` at the top. Rcpp-common says to add the `wrap` and `as` overloads before including `Rcpp.h`, this is why I had `RcppCommon.h` at the top.

Comment: @crea7or: Then I need to `delete` manually. And I don't know what R does internally, will it make multiple copies? If so, stuff might get `delete`d too early. The `wrap` function generated by Rcpp creates a new object, so that is at least one extra copy of the pointer, which I'd have to make sure doesn't get deleted.